# How to use the status bar in xamarin.forms shell?

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image]

I do not want to use full screen in android since there will be a bug.

I know how to do it in ios. please show me how to do it in android.

Comment: Add the line `Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
            Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
` before `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);`  in MainActivity .

Comment: it will make all page like that page I only want the first page. can it be set in the cs file?@LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: Hi,any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could implement it by using **Messaging Center** .

#### in  first page .cs

In your case it should be a shell

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();

   MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this,"Hide");
                
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
   base.OnDisappearing();

    MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "Show");
}
```

#### in Android project -> MainActivity

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "Hide", (arg) => {

            Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
            Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);

        });

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "Show", (arg) => {

            Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
            Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);

        });

      


        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

Comment: according to your code the tab bar menu can not be tapped,please try.it will tap to the system menu

Comment: It is by design in Shell. It will work in normal ContentPage .

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/184144/how-to-use-safe-area-in-xamarin-forms-android

Comment: Zhang  what is "It is by design in Shell" mean?

Comment: As i said it is by design in Shell which we could set  . Your requirment can only implement in normal ContentPage .

Comment: @then it will not work in Shell.right? and If I want to use Shell I can not use immersive?